# ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here it shows the error when i use & sign

Tags: sql, oracle

why it shows the error under the &gt when i am making the trigger in oracel sql developer

[image]

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: What is `&gt` (and its variations) doing in that code?

Comment: You must use symbol `>` insyead of `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

2 things: use `>` instead of `&gt`, and `:=` is extraneous.